# Unzip mutiple files in multiple sub folders

Tags: batch, batch-file, zip, rar

I have a bunch of zipped files (.rar , .zip) spread out in multiple sub folders but all in the same base folder (F:\1).

I was wondering if there was a way to unzip each file while still retaining its original name
(zipped file.zip would turn into F:\1\zipped file).

And if possible delete the original zip file just keeping the unzipped folder.

Is there a way to do this with a batch file so i don't have to do each folder at a time?

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

your qestion is quite ambigous. An archive usually contains more than one file and may have subfolders included. If you want to create a `folder` with the same name as the archive (without extension) and store all archive content in there this is a starting point.

```
:: Expand-Archive.cmd :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set Base=F:\1
if exist "%~1" Set "Base=%~f1"
Pushd %Base% ||(Echo Can't cd to base folder %base% &Pause&Exit)
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B/S/A-D *.zip *.rar') Do Call :Expand "%%A"
PopD
Goto :Eof

:Expand
Set "_Folder=%~dp1"
PushD "%_Folder%"
Set "_Archive=%~nx1"
Set "_NewSubFolder=%~dpn1"
:: Your own code to expand the Archive goes here.
:: I don't know what tool (7zip Infozip etc.) you usually use.
::
:: with 7z somewhere in your path this might work,
:: remove Echo in the following 2 Lines.
Echo MkDir  "%_NewSubFolder%"
Echo 7z x -O"%_NewSubFolder%" "%_Archive%" && Del "%_Archive%"
PopD
Goto :Eof
:: Expand-Archive.cmd :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

HTH